# Plotting error in scipy.interplot Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to plot a smooth line with the following code:

```
from scipy.interpolate import spline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import collections
from matplotlib.ticker import ScalarFormatter, FormatStrFormatter

t1 = np.arange(1, 35, 1)
t2 = [479772,479772,479772,479772,479772,479772,479772,479772,
     479772,479772,479772,479772,479772,479772,479772,479772,479772,
     479772,479772,479772,479772,479772,479772,479819,479819,479819,
     479819,479819,479819,479878,479878,479878,479878,479878]

P = t2
T = t1

xnew = np.linspace(T.min(),T.max(),33)

P_smooth = spline(T,P,xnew)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
fig.set_size_inches(7, 4, forward=True)
plt.ticklabel_format(useOffset=False)
plt.plot(xnew,P_smooth, '--k')
plt.xlabel('$w$')
plt.ylabel('z')
plt.show()
```

As you may notice, there seems a decrease in z when w is 23 and 29 on the plot. However, as you can see in the `t2` list, there is no decrease anywhere. Any suggestions to correct this issue?

Comment: Maybe it is worth noting that if you use the same points as the input `xnew = np.linspace(T.min(),T.max(),34)` (34 instead of 33) you would get a line through all points. This would be the same as plotting `plt.plot(T,P)`. Hence it's not really clear what you are trying to achieve here.

Comment: Well, I tried to play with that number. 33 also makes something weird. However, 5 makes it nicest. Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a cubic spline interpolation method. This may result in a curve that runs below the provided points. An alternative might be to use [interp1d](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/interpolate.html#d-interpolation-interp1d) for linear spline interpolation instead:

```
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
...
f = interp1d(t1, t2)
...
plt.plot(t1, t2, 'o', xnew, f(xnew), '-')
```

The resulting graph:

[image: interp1d]

Comment: That was what I was looking for. Thanks @Icary